# Autentificacion con otra tabla laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autenticación

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel 5.4 y quiero usar el sistema de autentificacion que trae, pero con la informacion que se encuntra en otra tabla que ya ha sido creada a travez de las migraciones.

La verdad es que he navegado por todo internet y he visto la documentacion, pero en ambos lados no he logrado obtener respuestas que me permitan realizar lo que necesito.

A lo maximo que he llegado es realizar la autentificacion pero sin redireccion, es decir, se envian los datos y luego llego a la misma view de login.

Dejo el codigo de lo que llevo.

**LoginController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller {

use AuthenticatesUsers;


public function username() {
    return 'usuario';
}

public function __construct() {

}

public function showLoginForm() {
    return view('auth.login');
}

public function login(Request $request) {
    // Validate the form data
    $this->validate($request, [
        'password' => 'required|min:2'
    ]);
    // Attempt to log the user in
    if (Auth::guard()->attempt(['usuario' => $request->usuario, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
        // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }
    // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('usuario', 'remember'));
}

}
```

Lo demas esta practicamente por defecto.
Cabe mencionar que genere la estructura de autentificacion con:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

---

Respuesta Shaz

Gracias por contestar.
He realizado lo que indicas, agrego el codigo de como tengo ambos archivos

**app/Acceso** (model)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Acceso extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
protected $guard = 'users';
protected $table = 'acceso';
protected $fillable = ['id', 'rol_id', 'personal_id', 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'activo'];
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

public function rol(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Rol');
}

public function personal(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Personal');
}
}
```

**config/auth.php**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Acceso::class,
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente la tabla la configuras en el modelo que está especificado en tu archivo config/auth.php :

```
...
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => app\Models\User::class,
    ],
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    //
],
...
```

En el modelo (en este caso en app/Models/User.php) defines la tabla que deseas utilizar:

```
...
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'users';

    // ...
}
```

Más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: Gracias por responder.
Agregue el codigo de como tengo ambos archivos, al parecer cumplen con lo que indicas. Ahora bien, avanzando un poco, me sale el siguiente error en la casilla de "usuario" -"These credentials do not match our records."- En color rojo.
No se si avancé o retrocedí.

Comment: @Israeljara los campos que validan también son distintos? O sea, no son email ni password.

Comment: Asi es, son usuario y password.

Answer (score 0):

Añade la clave table en tu archivo config/auth.php dentro del array providers => users.

Añade las propiedades y configuraciones que necesites al modelo encargado de llevar a cabo la autenticación.

Recuerda modificar el controlador App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController, más concretamente los métodos validator y create.

Todo debe funcionar perfectamente.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. He podido solucionar lo de la autentificacion sin saber como, algo modifique que al final funciono. Iba a volver a este tema a preguntar que puede haber sido. Revisare lo que mencionas, Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Yo sé exactamente porque pasa esto ve a home controlller debe haber un constructor con un middleware->('auth ') cámbialo a auth.basic, una de las razones por la cual no funciona es porque dentro de esa clase auth se encuentran directivas de para los métodos de guard, supongo que lo que hiciste fue modificar la clase que traía por defecto y pusiste tu código  si ves este código que trae por defecto traía  una función llamada guard la cual eliminastes y por ende la clase auth no encuentra el guard